# How to mangle IP addresses based on time using iptables

Tags: iptables, nat

I want to change my IP addresses based on time not urls. Following is my iptable rule to mangle IPs I have :

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o em1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT \
              --to x.x.x.118-y.y.y.128
```

The problem is everytime I check ipflag.com I only get one specific ip which I don't want it to be like that I want to have a rule in iptables so it would change my IP based on time, say every 5 mins.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: I think there should be a way to set time for rules in iptables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time module will deliver close to what you are wanting; the below covers 2:00am to 6:00am every day (read up on this module for further information as it does also allow for targeting on a per day of the week basis):

```
-m time --timestart 02:00 --timestop 06:00
```

but you would need to create many rules to achieve your "every 5 minutes" requirement.

Also note that because of the way the connection tracking module works, once a connection is established, it becomes tracked (an entry is added to the conntrack table) and it will remain that way, regardless of what iptables "time matching" rules you come up with for this, until it either expires (in the case of UDP) or is torn down (TCP connection closed/reset etc). So even if you did rotate to a different IP address every 5 minutes, if you have a persistent connection which remains open to a peer, that will not automatically terminate and reset - it will remain established without interruption using the IP address it first matched on (via your iptables "time matching" rules). To force a connection reset, moving it onto a new IP, you would have to also start using `conntrack` (part of the `conntrack-tools` RPM package) to actively reset all or some of the connections that you wish to be moved over to your new IP address. You could do a crontab entry to achieve this, running something like this every 5 minutes:

```
/usr/sbin/conntrack -D -s 192.168.0.128
```

to reset all connections being tracked originating from host 192.168.0.128 (run with just the -D to perform a complete blanket reset of all tracked connections).

Comment: I saw an extension called statistics but since I'm using ubuntu 14.04 seems it missed. if I can do it randomly I am happy too. do you have any idea about that?

Comment: You can also use the statistics iptables module, but my above point about using that in the NAT chain (connection tracking) still stands. You will still run up against the problem of connections remaining tracked until they either reset themselves or you actively force them to be reset. Also, from what I recall, the statistics module works either on a random basis or every nth matched packet etc, which doesn't quite address your requirement for "every 5 minutes".

Comment: It's becoming evident that this may be best achieved with a cronjob (using a */5 cronspec) calling a script which takes care of adjusting your NAT chain as required. I cannot recommend any other method myself (though others may know of a solution without going this route).

Comment: Just noticed you are using the round-robin feature: --to x.x.x.118-y.y.y.128 - in that case, you could just try running conntrack -D every 5 minutes and that should just rotate your connections onto alternative IP addresses within that range (it will reset any active sessions though). Worth a shot.