# Iptables hashlimit and nat

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking, nat

Hello I'm trying to create a PREROUTING rule in order to re-direct the traffic to another port based on hashlimit.

```
iptables -I PREROUTING -t nat -p udp --src 0/0 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.2.4:1053
```

This works fine and redirect everything from port 53 to 1053.

This using hashlimit seems to work:

```
iptables -I PREROUTING -t raw -p udp --dport 53 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-srcmask 32 --hashlimit-above 100/second --hashlimit-burst 1 --hashlimit-name OL_Proc -j DROP
```

But the following doesn't seems to work at all:

```
iptables -I PREROUTING -t nat -p udp --dport 53 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-srcmask 32 --hashlimit-above 100/second --hashlimit-burst 1 --hashlimit-name OL_Proc -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.2.4:1053
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

EDIT 1:

Based on the feedback of parkamark (which makes sense), I tried the following:

This works as expected and route all the traffic to a new IP/Port:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -j MARK --set-mark 1

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -m mark --mark 0x1 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.2.5:1053
```

But this doesn't work and I cannot understand why:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-srcmask 32 --hashlimit-above 100/second --hashlimit-burst 1 --hashlimit-htable-expire 300000 --hashlimit-name OL_Proc -j MARK --set-mark 1

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -m mark --mark 0x1 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.2.5:1053
```

I can see on the iptables -t mangle -L -v -n that the first rule is executed correctly but the second one is never triggered. I also included log on the first rule and I can verify that is triggered 100%.

Any idea/feedback on this?

Answer (score 0):

No you are not doing something wrong.

NAT connections are tracked in the connection tracking table within the kernel. You can view this table at any moment in time using the `conntrack` command (`conntrack -L` is a good start) - you may need to `yum install conntrack-tools` if it's not available on your system.

As I have previously explained [here](https://serverfault.com/a/780809/30506), when it comes to NAT, iptables rules defined against the `-t nat` table define how packets are initially matched for adding them into the connection tracking table. After this initial match/hit on the iptables rule, the session will be added to the connection tracking table, and all related packets will be dealt with via NAT within the kernel, either until the connection times out (no traffic seen within a certain period of time), the connection is torn down/terminated (in the case of TCP) or you use the `conntrack -D` option to delete the NAT rule from the connection tracking table, so it is no longer tracked.

In the context of your question, the first rule is on the `raw` table, directing traffic to `-j DROP` which is an immediate drop of traffic, where NAT is not involved. In your second rule, which is on the `nat` table, `-j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.2.4:1053` is matching packets and adding initial session packets into the connection tracking table, after which any further related traffic between the client source IP/port and destination IP/port `10.0.2.4:1053` will no longer be matched by any iptables `nat` rules.

Comment: Understood. But is there any alternative way to do what I need through iptables?

Comment: What is it you need? I'm presuming it's a rate-limiting of packets towards `10.0.2.4:1053` - the iptables example you've given which applies a rule to the `raw` table should be sufficient to do this as packets are matched within the `raw` table before reaching the `nat` one.

Comment: I need to route the traffic to another ip/port when it's crossing a specific limit of packets/second. I Edit my initial question by performing a new test based on your great feedback (Thanks) but I really cannot understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you are asking because of the nature of NAT and the connection tracking that's going on. Once a connection tracking rule has been populated into the conntrack table, that's the session fixated between the client and your internal server - you can't just magically move it to another internal host later based on some iptables rule. I would question *why* you are trying to do this, because to me, it feels like you should be using some kind of load-balanced vip solution which would share the load across several nodes with health-checking thrown in.